# Как пофиксить неуклюжий прыжок фиксированного меню при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Добрый день, сообщество. На сайте https://oblakavape.com.ua/ при скролле вниз происходит "неуклюжий" прыжок меню, сразу после добавления класса .fixed к блоку навигации. Как можно исправить данную проблему? Решение с клонированием меню сюда не подойдет. Прикладываю js код, который отвечает за фиксированную навигацию.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
        $('.navigation').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.navigation').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачет не меню, а контент под блоком. При добавлении к меню `position: fixed`, меню выходит из блочной модели, ровно также, как и при `position: absolute`. 
Предлагаю такой выход: обернуть весь контент, который идет после меню, в отдельный блок, а затем добавлять padding при скролле.
css:

```
.body_scroll {
  padding-top: *высота меню*;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
    $('.navigation').addClass('fixed');
    $(*селектор блока-обертки*).addClass('body_scroll');
} else {
    $('.navigation').removeClass('fixed');
    $(*селектор блока-обертки*).removeClass('body_scroll');
}
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Подумывал о подобном решении.